# How do I connect to AWS RDS MySQL from Java/Spring application using AWS IAM Authentication?

Tags: java, spring-data, amazon-rds, spring-jdbc, amazon-iam

I am new to AWS world and still learning. It's been only a month that I am trying things.

I have been looking for it for quite a few days now and haven't been able to find a correct and more appropriate solution. Therefore it would be great if somebody can help me by giving a sample code, provide some pointer or guide in the right direction.

I have a **AWS RDS MySQL** instance and a database created. I have configured "**IAM DB AUthentication Enabled**" to "Yes".

Created an **IAM Role** and **Policy** as per AWS documentation.

And finally, I have an **EC2 instance** with Tomcat with my **Java/Spring application** deployed and running in it. I am able to access the MySQL database using database credentials (like db user name, password, db url, etc.) successfully. So I know things are setup properly now.

Can somebody please help me know how to connect to this database from my Java/Spring application using **spring-jdbc** and **AWS IAM Authentication** (the IAM role I created above)?

I read somewhere that I need the **certificate file** or certificate bundle file in my application environment and that I need to generate a **token** to be connected to the database. But I am not able to think on how to put it together.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: seems [this is the doc](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/users-connect-rds-iam/) seems you need to implement a connection factory

Comment: @gusto2 - thanks for the reply, appreciated. I came across that link however, it's more of a setup (which I have done, the girl in the video appears to use some old console UI) and trying things from command prompt. I am looking for doing it programmatically  in my Java/Spring application. Any pointers on that will be helpful.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50847945/accessing-aws-rds-using-iam-authentication-and-spring-jdbc-datasource-and-jdbct/51023536#51023536

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem recently.

This is what I did:

- Included Spring Cloud AWS JDBC and Spring Data JPA
- Implemented a custom DataSourceFactory, which generates an IAM access token and uses that for the connection

You can find a full step-by-step guide [here](https://masteringaws.blogspot.com/2018/11/accessing-rds-mysql-with-spring-cloud.html).

Btw., Spring Cloud AWS JDBC provides some additional benefits, like read replica or failover support, and you only have to provide the instance ID of your RDS instance, and not the full canonical endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated for 2023!**

This can now be accomplished even more easily using the [AWS JDBC Driver for MySQL](https://awslabs.github.io/aws-mysql-jdbc/) support for [IAM Database Authentication](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mysql-jdbc#aws-iam-database-authentication).  I tested out this configuration with Spring Boot 3 & spring-boot-starter-jdbc.

Add the following dependencies:

```
runtimeOnly 'software.aws.rds:aws-mysql-jdbc:1.1.6'
runtimeOnly 'software.amazon.awssdk:rds:2.20.57'
```

Add the following to application.yml:

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    jdbc-url: jdbc:mysql:aws://yourdbcluster-xxxx.cluster-xxxx.your-region.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/yourdb
    username: iam_username
    #password: dont-need-this
    driver-class-name: software.aws.rds.jdbc.mysql.Driver
    data-source-properties:
      useAwsIam: true
```

And it should just work!

The driver uses the [AWS default credentials provider chain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/credentials-chain.html) so make sure you have credentials with policy allowing IAM DB access available wherever you are running your app.  To configure failover support, review the documentation [here](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mysql-jdbc#connection-url-descriptions).  Hope this update helps someone else!

---

**This is an older method using MariaDB driver - see updates above!*

I know this is an older question, but after a some searching I found a pretty easy way you can now do this using the MariaDB driver. In version 2.5 they added an [AWS IAM credential plugin](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-connector-j-250-release-notes) to the driver. It will handle generating, caching and refreshing the token automatically.

I've tested using Spring Boot 2.3 with the default HikariCP connection pool and it is working fine for me with these settings:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://host/db?credentialType=AWS-IAM&useSsl&serverSslCert=classpath:rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=iam_username
#spring.datasource.password=dont-need-this
spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=600000
```

Download [rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html) and put it in `src/main/resources` so you can connect via SSL.
You will need these dependencies on the classpath as well:

```
runtime 'org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client'
runtime 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-rds:1.11.880'
```

The driver uses the standard `DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain` so make sure you have credentials with policy allowing IAM DB access available wherever you are running your app.

Addionally, if you want failover support like @markusgulden mentioned in his answer, you can use the `aurora` mode described [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/failover-and-high-availability-with-mariadb-connector-j/#failover-and-load-balancing-modes).  Your endpoint would then look like

`jdbc:mariadb:aurora://host/db?credentialType=AWS-IAM&useSsl&serverSslCert=classpath:rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem`

Hope this helps someone else - most examples I found online involved custom code, background threads, etc - but using the new driver feature is much easier!

Comment: Nice answer. In case you want to use the MariaDB and RDS IAM auth from your favorite SQL IDE, it's a bit hard to find which JARs are required. We worked on a light-weight library which supports both MySQL and MariaDB drivers: https://github.com/team-carepay/carepool-aws-jdbc . If you add the `carepool-aws-jdbc-2.1.7-all.jar` next to the MySQL or MariaDB driver, you're all set.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using this library that you use to replace the HikariDatasource. Everything else just works like normal.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.volcanolabs</groupId>
  <artifactId>rds-iam-hikari-datasource</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```