# How to connect to RDS with IAM authentication using Hibernate

Tags: amazon-web-services, hibernate, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-iam

Is there a way to use Hibernate as an ORM framework for AWS lambda and use IAM authentication to connect to the RDS instance?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the type of database and [`ConnectionProvider`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#database) you are using. As an example for MariaDB you can use the [AWS IAM credential plugin](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-connector-j-250-release-notes/) that was added to the driver.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can connect an RDS instance using IAM authentication, and since you can use your code in a lambda, then you can do it ! Here is a link you can follow, and some resources on internet can guide you in your journey:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/iam-role-based-authentication-to-amazon-aurora-from-serverless-applications/

and another more general:

https://ordina-jworks.github.io/cloud/2022/06/13/aws-rds-iam-authentication-spring-boot.html

do not forget to enable iam authentication on your rds instance or cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [AWS JDBC Driver for MySQL](https://awslabs.github.io/aws-mysql-jdbc/) - it has support for [IAM DB Authentication](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mysql-jdbc#aws-iam-database-authentication).  You should be able to use it as a drop-in replacement for the MySQL driver.  I've used it successfully in a Spring Boot + Spring Data JPA (hibernate) application - check out my updated answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64451898/1296598).