# Auto refresh RDS IAM token credentials

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-rds, amazon-iam

I am trying to connect to AWS RDS after assume rule using JAVA and IAM token , and im getting expired security token errors after an hour,is there any way to auto refresh the token?

I found a way to do this on sqs connection , but i unable to find the same way on rds connection.

Comment: Not sure what framework you are using, but maybe my answers here will help: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64451227/1296598
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64503951/1296598

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Scheduler to refresh the RDS IAM Token after a set interval. Here I have created a Scheduler in Spring Boot application and refresh the token in the hikari pool connection object.

```
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 14*60*1000)
            public void refreshedRDSToken() throws Exception {
                HikariDataSource datasource = (HikariDataSource) dbDataSource();
                HikariConfigMXBean hikariConfigMXBean = datasource.getHikariConfigMXBean();
                
                LOGGER.info(String.format("Start refreshing tokens in %s...", hikariConfigMXBean.getPoolName()));
                hikariConfigMXBean.setPassword(getToken());
                
                 HikariPoolMXBean pool = datasource.getHikariPoolMXBean();
                 if (pool != null) {
                      pool.softEvictConnections();  // Close unused cnxns & mark open ones for disposal
                      pool.resumePool();    // Re-enable connections 
                } 
        }

        @Autowired
        private RdsIamAuthTokenGenerator rdsclient;

   

 public String getToken() {
            
        Integer port = Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("port"));
        String host = env.getProperty("hostname");
        String userName = env.getProperty("token-user");
        GetIamAuthTokenRequest request = GetIamAuthTokenRequest.builder()
                    .hostname(host)
                    .port(port)
                    .userName(userName).build();
        String authToken = rdsclient.getAuthToken(request);
        //LOGGER.info("Generated Auth Token for datasource..."+authToken);
        return authToken;
        }
```